# User as both meeting room and incoming email address in Exchange

Tags: exchange

We have a new meeting room with a smart TV in it. The TV can accept email to easily display documents sent to it. We'd like to use the same email address both for checking this inbox **and** as the meeting room type in Exchange Online so it's easy for users to remember the information. Is this possible to do, or will we need to use two separate accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the TV using that same account, I would create an inbox rule that forwards all incoming messages that are not Calendar appointments to the TV. That way the TV is not trying to display all of the calendar invitations.

Comment: Would we need to use a standard inbox for the account, then forward all calendar requests to a meeting room? Meeting rooms can't handle email like that, can they?

Comment: No, the other way around. Leave your meeting room mailbox, and create one for the TV (and hide it). Add the rule to your meeting room mailbox. A meeting room mailbox is just a normal mailbox under the covers.